# Merging Data Frame with mix Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data_frames `df1` and `df2`. I want to merge them but the `Value` column is mixed `int` and `float` numbers from an excel I have. However, I know I cannot merge `int or float` columns. So I converted both `df1 and df2` into `str` and merge. However I want to keep the `type` of it. If it is a `int` or `float`.

**INPUT**

```
df1:
    Value       Desc
0   10          A
1   2.0         B
2   3.5         C
3   4.7         D
4   1           E

df2:

    Value       Size
0   5           3
1   10          4
2   1           1
3   2.0         5
4   17          25
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    Value       Desc    Size
0   10          A       4
1   2.0         B       5
4   1           E       1
```

but reminding that `10 and 1` should be `int` and `2.0` should be float. I need it because I will do some operations in the future with `type()`

Comment: Is there a categorical value you could assign to each object in each row? Merging on numerical values doesn't seem like a great idea. If you really want to do it that way, you could create a new column in each dataframe, `merge_col` that is `float(df.Value)`. You could merge on this column and then preserve the types in `Value`

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein but when I do that and try to merge the `Value` column will be gone because `pd.merge` loses the data when the column is numerical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column in one of your df before merging:

```
df1['type'] = [type(x) for x in df1['Value']]
```